# `BCEWithLogitsLoss` and training class dataset imbalances in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, pytorch

A bit of clarification on pytorch's [`BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss): I am using : `pos_weights = torch.tensor([len_n/(len_n + len_y), len_y/(len_n + len_y)])` to initialize the loss, with `[1.0, 0.0]` being the negative class and `[0.0, 1.0]` being the positive class, and `len_n, len_y` being respectively the length of negative and positive samples.

The reason to use `BCEWithLogitsLoss` in the first place is precisely because I assume that it is compensating an imbalance between the quantity of positive and negative samples by avoiding the network from simply "defaulting" to the most abundant class type in the training set. I want to control the priorization of the loss on detecting the less abundant class correctly. In my case, negative train samples exceed positive samples by a factor of 25 to 1, so it is very important that the network predicts a high fraction of positive samples correctly, rather than having a high overall prediction rate (even by defaulting always to negative, that would lead to 96% prediction if I only cared about that).

**Question** Is it correct my assumption about `BCEWithLogitsLoss` using the `pos_weights` parameter to control training class imbalances? Any insight into how the imbalance is being addressed in the loss evaluation?

Comment: since the number of samples is 25x larger than negative samples, did you mean to say `"so it is very important that the network predicts a high fraction of negative samples correctly."`?

Comment: sorry @kmario23 I meant exactly the opposite, fixed the question